# Replace header text with excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to modify my current code to replace specified words in a MSWord document. The whole idea is working but only for the body of the document and nothing happening in the header or in the footer. Can you please advise me where am I wrong ?

Thank you in advance!

```
Sub FindAndReplace(ByVal FindWord, ByVal ReplaceWord)

WordApp.ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Execute FindText:=FindWord, Wrap:=1, ReplaceWith:=ReplaceWord, Replace:=2
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5834-word-find-and-replace-in-header-footer.html

Comment: You can refer to the code provided in this link below:https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-change-file-properties-author.210142/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub FindAndReplace(ByVal FindWord, ByVal ReplaceWord)
Dim oStory as WordApp.Range
For Each oStory in WordApp.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    oStory.Find.Execute _
        FindText:=FindWord, ReplaceWith:=ReplaceWord, Wrap:=1, Replace:=2
Next oStory
Set oStory = Nothing
End Sub
```